# How to install samples/libraries?

Tags: botframework

For some reason, the github page here https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples has **no instructions** on how to actually add the sample/functionality to your own bot.

I'm trying to add this library to my composer bot project: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library but it itself doesn't have any instructions either, just how to download it via git (which I've done).

The only guide I could find is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-custom-action?tabs=csharp but it doesn't quite match up with the library above.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The samples repo is not a library. It's literally a list of smaller bots that can be run locally, in every GA'd language SDK of the Bot Framework. It's not meant to be 'installed'. The purpose of the various samples are to show how the SDK can be leveraged for certain scenarios, so you can take the code and implement it for yourself, or mimic the code in your own bot. If there's a certain sample who's functionality you want in your bot, such as "How to add attachment handling", you should ask that.

Comment: Okay, that explains some things, but isn't still strange that those samples don't have implementation instructions? Just seems like the people who create those samples would want it to propagate/become popular. I'm not a C# person so maybe I'm not seeing how easy it is to implement.